# I have been working on a custom language translator. It works and all, but, when I try typing a comma it shows a bunch of errors

Tags: python

It works fine when I enter something, but when I do something like "hi, amazing." it shows a bunch of errors. Here is the code.

```
a = {"hi": "hoi", "ability": "yoruko", "able": "boloi", "about": "oklo", "above": "nad", "amazing": "amazo"}
Answer = input("Language? (Set) ")
if Answer == "Set":
    something = input("Say something to be translated. ") #get input
    Say2 = something.split() #split into list
    for i in Say2: #for loop
        print(a[i])
```

Edit: Error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(a[i])
KeyError: 'hi,'
```

Comment: **Hint**: In your example, `Say2 = ['hi,', 'amazing.']`. Is there any entry in `a` with the key `'hi,'` (note the comma)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is that when you split `something` there's a trailing comma, because the value of `something` is 'hi, amazing', by splitting what you have is `['hi,', 'amazing']` and `'hi,'` is not in the dictionary.

You need to do some input control. In fact, in this particular case, you can use:

```
Say2 = something.split(",")
```

And it will work, but what will happen if you add a colon, a semi-colon, etc?

One solution is to use a regex to handle all the punctuation marks at once:

```
import re
Say2 = re.split('; |, |. |: ', something)
```

But a more robust approach consist in using `get` to check if the value is in the dictionary before trying to print. Something like:

```
print(a.get(i, "No translation available"))
```

Or with an exception:

```
try:
    print(a[i])
except KeyError:
    print("No translation available")
```

Wrapping all this up:

```py
import re

a = {"hi": "hoi", "ability": "yoruko", "able": "boloi", "about": "oklo", "above": "nad", "amazing": "amazo"}
Answer = input("Language? (Set) ")
if Answer == "Set":
    something = input("Say something to be translated. ") #get input
    Say2 = re.split('; |, |. |: ', something) #split into list
    for i in Say2: #for loop
        print(a.get(i, "no translation available"))
```

Comment: ok, but when I do this and enter something to be translated with a "," it doesn't show that in the output. Do I have to change the original translations?

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't see the other ones. But when I tried the last one, nothing would appear when I tried to translate something.